# Accessing controller array from directive

Tags: angularjs

I would like to use a scope variable in my directive:

```
app.controller('YEL', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', 'ngMeta', function($scope, $routeParams, $http, ngMeta) {   
    $http.get('xxx').success(function(res) {
        $scope.yels = res; /* Array */

    }).error(function(res, status) {
        ...
    });

}]);
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="yel in yels">
    <div plangular="{{yel.soundcloud}}" ng-if="yel.soundcloud" >
        <div ng-if="track" id="{{yel.id}}" ng-click="playPause()" title="Play/Pause" ">
            <i ng-if="player.playing !== track.src" class="fa fa-2x fa-play grow" aria-hidden="false"></i>
            <i ng-if="player.playing === track.src" class="fa fa-2x fa-pause grow" aria-hidden="false"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my Plangular directive:

```
plangular.directive('plangular', ['$timeout', 'plangularConfig', function($timeout, plangularConfig) {
  var player = new Player();

  return {

    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,

    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      var src = attr.plangular;
      scope.player = player;
      scope.audio = player.audio;
      scope.track = true;

    ...
      player.audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        if (scope.track.src === player.audio.src) {
          scope.next();
        } else { 
            if (scope.repeatclicked) {
                this.play(src);
                console.log(scope.yel.id);

            }               
        }           
      });   
    ...
    }
  }


}]);
```

Is there a way to use that `yel.id` defined in the ng-repeat in my directive? I'm trying `console.log(scope.yel.id);` without any success.

**EDIT**

I've added an attribute to the directive as suggested by @Maak, I'm now passing `yel-id={{yel.id}}` to the directive, but the output of my `console.log(attr.yelId)` is the {{yel.id}} of all the yel inside the yels array, as shown in the image:

[image]

I would like to logging only the yelId of the single directive, somthing like `console.log(this.attr.yelId);`

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the `yel` object to the directive by changing the following.

Pass the `yel` object to your directive

```
<div ng-repeat="yel in yels">
    <div plangular="yel" ng-if="yel.soundcloud" >
       <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Include the `yel` object in your scope directive

```
plangular.directive('plangular', function($timeout, plangularConfig) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            plangular: '='
        },
        // ...
    }
});
```

Afterwards you can access the `id` of your `yel` object in the directive with

```
link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
  console.log(scope.plangular.id)
}
```

---

**Alternatively** you can also pass the id by using a different custom attribute.

```
<div ng-repeat="yel in yels">
    <div plangular="{{yel.soundcloud}}" yel-id={{yel.id}} ng-if="yel.soundcloud" >
       <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And then access that attribute in your directive with

```
 link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
  console.log(attr.yelId)
}
```

Comment: But I have to keep plangular="yel.soundcloud" or my directive won't work.

Comment: You could access `yel.soundcloud` with `scope.yel.soundcloud` in your directive, or if you want to keep  `plangular="yel.soundcloud" ` you can add an extra attribute to your html (see edit)

Comment: The second approach almost worked, but I logged all the attr.yelId of all the yels controller array. How can I use only the yelId that is being observed?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Every directive will log the id, since every directive has an attribute yell-id. How is it determined which id is being observed?

Comment: I edited the question. I don't get why I'm loggin all the yelId and not only the one associated to the directive.

Comment: Since the your plangular directive is used inside the `ngRepeat` it will be called as many  time as you as elements in your `yels` element.